# Why is the N-N bond length greater in dinitrogen trioxide than in dinitrogen tetroxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

> Why is the N-N bond length greater in dinitrogen trioxide than in dinitrogen tetroxide?

If the lone pair on $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{N2O3}$ delocalises, then the $\ce{N-N}$ bond will have a double bond character, so it should be shorter.

From data on Wikipedia, the $\ce{N-N}$ bond length in [dinitrogen trioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_trioxide?oldformat=true) is  $\pu{186.4pm}$ while that of [dinitrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide) is $\pu{178pm}$.

Comment: I am thinking this is a very tough question. Here's a [research paper on this topic](http://www.crawford.chem.vt.edu/PDF/JChemPhys_106_7178.pdf). Read from "The $\ce{N–N}$ bond distance is exceptionally long $\pu{1.75–1.78 Å}$! while the..." second paragraph.

Comment: @GaurangTandon This paper highlights that N-N bond is exceptionally long in dinitrogen teroxide. But why is it longer in dinitrogen trioxide?

Comment: Indeed, it is. But, I do not know the exact answer. I was just linking to a related paper.

Comment: So is this an anomaly or is there an explanation to it?

Comment: @Parth there is no such thing as an anomaly , just things for which reasons haven't been found yet.